# Command Line Index

Tags: javascript, command-line-arguments, argv

I am sending the following text through the command line and not sure how to extract the different names in the -q tag
command:  `-s 127.0.0.1:3000 -q test1.pdf test2.pdf test3.pdf test4.pdf-v 7`

The number of file names being sent in can change

This is how I am currently parsing through
`var s = process.argv.indexOf('-s') + 1;let files = process.argv.indexOf('-q') + 1; let version = process.argv.indexOf('-v') + 1;`

`let fileName = process.argv[files ].split(' ')`

Any recommendations on what to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement this vary basic solution, iterating through the arguments and picking those which contain "*.pdf*" in them.

```js
for (i of process.argv) {
    if (i.includes(".pdf")) {
        //i is your filename now, do something with it
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Differently, if you don't only have one type of file extension, you could apply a closer solution to what you were already guessing, assuming that the file-names are **always** contained within the `-q` and `-v` flags:

```js
let fIdx = process.argv.indexOf('-q'); 
let vIdx = process.argv.indexOf('-v'); 

for (i of process.argv.slice(fIdx+1,vIdx)) {
    //i is your filename now, do something with it
    console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally for command line arguments, if each test*.pdf file was supposed to belong to the -q option, I would expect to see them listed as either:

```
-q "test1.pdf,test2.pdf,test3.pdf,test4.pdf"
```

or

```
-q test1.pdf -q test2.pdf -q test3.pdf -q test4.pdf
```

Both of these styles will make the logic much easier to parse in addition to being a more conventional style.

Also, I would suggest you look into the **[yargs module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)** (https://yargs.js.org/) for parsing arguments.

**Update**:
If the input can't be changed, then I'd suggest working through the list of args and if it starts with a '-' char, remember that option and continue to collect all consecutive options into that array until you reach another flag.

Some rough code:

```
const opts = {}; // Hold all options
const optionPattern = /^(?<Prefix>-{1,2}|\/)(?<Flag>.*)/; // Support various styles: -s, --s, /s
let currFlag = 'Unknown'; // Bucket to hold any args not specifically marked

for (const elem of process.argv) {
    const matchResult = optionPattern.exec(elem);
    if (matchResult) {
        currFlag = matchResult.groups.Flag;
    } else {
        opts[currFlag] = opts[currFlag] || []; // Create the array if this is the first one
        opts[currFlag].push(elem);
    }
}

console.log(`Options Received: ${JSON.stringify(opts, null, 4)}`);
```

The above would output:

```
Options Received: {
"Unknown": [
    "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
    "C:\\Projects\\NodeTestScripting\\TestScripts\\CommandLineArgs.js"
],
"s": [
    "127.0.0.1:3000"
],
"q": [
    "test1.pdf",
    "test2.pdf",
    "test3.pdf",
    "test4.pdf"
],
"v": [
    "7"
]
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, it was asked of me to be able to identify the files being sent in that format. Not too sure how to go about it